# Matplotlib is only working with marker style graphs, how do I fix that?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I running a quick test before starting a school work and ran into this bizarre issue where altough the code runs just fine, the resulting plot is just. Empty.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl


x = np.array([np.arange(0,6,0.01)])
y = np.array([np.arange(0,6,0.01)])

pl.plot(x,y)
pl.show()
```

It *should* just be a line. Instead, I am getting this:
[Plot window with expected intervals but no actual line or dots or anything at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQySK.png).

And to make matters more mindboggling, using a marker style works as expected! If I replace

`pl.plot(x,y)`

with

`pl.plot(x,y, marker='o)`

I get a proper, if colorful, graph! I'm boggled and need help : (

Comment: mind the shape of `x` and `y`.  You can either plot the transpose of the arrays, `plt.plot(x.T,y.T)`. Or you can flatten the array, `plt.plot(x.flat,y.flat)`. Or just *not* use a 2D array from the beginning, `x = np.arange(0,6,0.01)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you don't plot, what you think you plot.

`x = np.array([np.arange(0,6,0.01)])` creates a numpy array, then puts that into a list and then creates another numpy array from this. So the plot function will try to plot several hundred lines consisting of only one point each. Which is why you don't see anything (a line with one point only is invisible in mpl). So just use the normal arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl


x = np.arange(0,6,0.01)
y = np.arange(0,6,0.01)

pl.plot(x,y)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you a lot, that solved it! I had assumed that if I didn't typecast like that I would end up with one of those range objects instead. I didn't realize it worked like that.